# python how to find where the elements of an array fit inside an array of values

Tags: python, numpy

I have a big 1D array of values, say all between 0 and 1. I have a second array that partition the [0,1] intervals into M bins, and I am trying to find the proper way to know which bin each of the big array values would fit in.
Something like:

```
big = np.random.random(10000000)
bins = np.arange(0,1,0.01)
results = np.zeros_like(big)
for i,b in enumerate(big):
  results[i] = np.argmin(b>bins)
```

but of course without the costly for loop....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for numpy.digitize()?

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html

```
numpy.digitize(big, bins)
```

Comment: fantastic, I completely missed this numpy feature! Thanks a ton